# filter and return only specific fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to create a request where I can extract a specific metric from Elasticsearch, so I could manage data faster.
I got rid of metadata and unnecessary data with a request as follow :

```
get localhost:9200/metricbeat-7.12.0/_search?size=2000&pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source
{
    "_source": ["@timestamp", "labels","prometheus"]
}
```

I get something like that which is closer to what I want. Now I would like an additional filter where I get only the metrics "prometheus.metrics.windows_cpu_time_total" and not the other metrics.

```
   {
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
            {
                "_source": {
                    "@timestamp": "2021-04-29T15:35:57.518Z",
                    "prometheus": {
                        "metrics": {
                            "windows_service_status": 0
                        },
                        "labels": {
                            "instance": "localhost:9182",
                            "name": "timebrokersvc",
                            "job": "prometheus",
                            "status": "lost comm"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_source": {
                    "@timestamp": "2021-04-29T15:35:57.518Z",
                    "prometheus": {
                        "metrics": {
                            "windows_cpu_time_total": 29480.625
                        },
                        "labels": {
                            "mode": "idle",
                            "core": "0,0",
                            "instance": "localhost:9182",
                            "job": "prometheus"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }}]}}
```

I tried a field search which doesn't seem to work as well. Could someone point me to what's going wrong with my queries?

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
    "fields": [
    "prometheus.metrics", 
    {
        "field": "windows_cpu_time_total"
    }]
  }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In elasticsearch version 7.10 and 7.11, `fields` functionality was in beta version, as stated in the official [documentataion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/search-fields.html#search-fields-param)

But in elasticsearch version 7.12, the `fields` option, is working fine

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2021-04-29T15:35:57.518Z",
  "prometheus": {
    "metrics": {
      "windows_cpu_time_total": 29480.625
    },
    "labels": {
      "mode": "idle",
      "core": "0,0",
      "instance": "localhost:9182",
      "job": "prometheus"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
POST _search?size=2000&pretty&filter_path=hits.hits
{
  "query": {
   "match_all": {}
  },
  "fields": [
    "prometheus.metrics.windows_cpu_time_total"
  ],
  "_source": false
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67588900",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "fields": {
          "prometheus.metrics.windows_cpu_time_total": [
            29480.625
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here an overview of the index mapping

```
"prometheus": {
                "properties": {
                    "*": {
                        "properties": {
                            "counter": {
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "histogram": {
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "rate": {
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "value": {
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        }
                    "metrics": {
                            "properties": {
                        "*": {
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "windows_cpu_time_total": {
                            "type": "double"
                        },}}
```

Comment: @Sofiane please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ? And which version of elasticsearch are you using ?

Comment: Hey @ESCODER i use elasticsearch 7.12. I tried what you wrote above but I receive an empty result "{}".

Comment: @Sofiane I have also tested the above query in 7.12. Can you please share your index mapping ?

Comment: @Sofiane I need to see mapping of `prometheus.metrics.windows_cpu_time_total`

Comment: i have the following mapping."prometheus": {
                    "properties": {
                        "metrics": {
                            "properties": {
                                "*": {
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "windows_cpu_time_total": {
                                    "type": "double"
                                },
}

Comment: i have this a well. I'm not sure if this can help as well. "query": {
                            "properties": {
                                "*": {
                                    "type": "object"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

Comment: @Sofiane and what about the `prometheus` field ? This field is not there in your index mapping `{ "properties": { "metrics": { "properties": { "*": { "type": "object" }, "windows_cpu_time_total": { "type": "double" }, }

Answer (score 0):

@ESCoder I couldn't post a comment anymore. I'll answer your question here. Here is the overview of the mapping with Prometheus properties included.

```
"prometheus": {
                "properties": {
                    "*": {
                        "properties": {
                            "counter": {
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "histogram": {
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "rate": {
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "value": {
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        }
                    "metrics": {
                            "properties": {
                        "*": {
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "windows_cpu_time_total": {
                            "type": "double"
                        },}}
```